# can't create a "curve => circle"

Tags: objects

I am watching a [video on creating a 3d Apple watch](https://rb.gy/b7hmy) model and am supposed to add a circle for the band, but it appears that they removed it sometime during updating Blender and I don't have that many options when clicking:
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> *Add > Curve*.

But I can't find *Circle*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into user preferences and search add-on's for "curve" - make sure *Add Curve: Curve Tools* and *Add Curve: Extra Objects* are enabled:

[image: Curves]

Once they are enabled, the  extra curves (including the circle) should appear in the *Add Menu* under *Curve*.